# Best way to add new user with different levels php

Tags: php, sql

I have created an application in PHP that has users and the users have different levels, lets just say 1, 2, 3, 4. When the user logs in it sets a session with their level number in it. The application shows different pages depending on user level like so:

```
if($role_level > 3)
{
    //Show something
}
```

Now I want to create an add user section where the user can add a new user and define them a role probably from a drop down (html select) box. But they can only define a role that is lower than their own. I'm thinking something like this:

```
<select>
    ("SELECT * FROM `roles` WHERE `roles_level` < $role_level)
    loop results into <options></options>
</select>
```

Any comments on this? Better ways to go about it? Will the above be affective?

Comment: You're on the money tbh there's not really any better ways of doing it unless you want to get mad complex with acl stuff.

Comment: Make sure you also validate the assigned role on the server side *before* inserting the new user. Just because the roles are not limited on the frontend, doesnt mean it cannot be tampered with. It's trivial to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea seem viable but it's not very flexible because it allows for a single direct hierarchy between roles. What if you need branching roles? For example, you may now have "users", "publishers", "reviewers" and "admins" as your current 1, 2, 3, and 4.

users can only read articles, publishers can also write and edit their articles, reviewers can also edit other publishers' articles and admin can also do admin stuff.

what if you want a moderator role? A moderator can edit articles, of anybody, but not write new articles. How would you implement that? You can't with your current model.

I suggest you to define a "roles" table, an "actions" table, and an N-M relationship table between them:

Roles:

- 1, user
- 2, publisher
- 3, reviewer
- 4, admin
- 5, article_moderator

Actions:

- 1, read_post
- 2, write_post
- 3, edit_own_post
- 4, edit_others_post
- 5, administrative_tools

Roles_Actions:

- 1,1
- 2,1
- 2,2
- 2,3
- 3,1
- 3,2
- 3,3
- 3,4
- 4,1
- 4,2
- 4,3
- 4,4
- 4,5
- 5,1
- 5,4 
  (note that moderators (5) can't write_own_post or even edit_own_post but only edit_others_post)

sure, this is more complex, but its more flexible for the future

I suggest you to read this answer too: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033401/998759) by @Vyktor which explains the ACL concept, useful for larger projects

Comment: +1, we were using this model in my previous work and it worked great, but if you really wanted it to be flexible you'd need to specify `Resource` table too, so you could reuse `action` and won't create prefixes like `forum_1_`, `forum_2_`, `wiki_`, `news_`...

Comment: yeah, i agree, but we also have to keep track of the scope of the project, which in this case i presume it's small or educational, thus not needing too much detail.

Comment: @STT LCU I think your answer is true. but mine can add something to it.

Comment: Totally agree, but I find it worth at least pointing out that there is such a thing, for example showing [how Zend does it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html).

Comment: sure thing @Vyktor it's important to define that flexible solutions are much better than easy solutions 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I think STT LCU already provided a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16032701/1149736), but for studying purposes (*yes, this is just an extension*) I'd like to add example how this can (and is done) in production environments, my favorite example - [Zend Framework's **A**ccess **C**ontrol **L**ists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html).

They specify three separate items/objects/not sure how to call them:

- **Resource** - what are you referring to, this can be *large items* such as `Forums`, `News`, `Articles`... or *atomic items* such as `Forums_<forum_id>_others_posts_title`. This should depend on how many users are you expecting and how complex the structure is. If you will have just 10 users and one admin, you'll be fine with one resource for whole site. On the another hand... Imagine you're google, have thousands of applications under your control and you want to propose unified and centralized ACL control... Many, many, many resources.
- **Role** - this should be self explanatory, but examples: `Banned`, `Visitor`, `User`, `ForumModerator`, `ArticlesModerator`, `SiteAdministrator`. In optimal framework (such as mentioned Zend) you can build hierarchy and inherit access among roles.
- **Access Control** - `Visitor can list list articles, but cannot read them`... This is again thing that should be intuitive, but here's a little controversy:

  - *Using hierarchy* - let's say you specify hierarchy like this `none < list < read < write < create < edit < delete` and having one automatically grands you all to the left, for example write automatically grants you read and list. This is nice, intuitive... But here's one example when this methodology is useless: *Black box*, where you want users to post items, but not to read them.
  - *Using flags* - **x chmod style* where access is determined from `flag`:

    - 1 - execute/list content of directory
    - 2 - write
    - 4 - read
      Where you can use binary and to check access: `access&WRITE`, or use sql schema with large number of columns.

To sum up: there's large number of things you can do, I really **do recommend** to read about Zend's ACLs so you'll get feeling how the API **may** look, maybe you'll realize some possible drawbacks you wouldn't think of on your own.

Comment: thank you. If you agree, i'll add a link to your answer, too.

Comment: @STTLCU I'll be glad :) go ahead ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will have every number available (i.e., you wont go 1, 2, 5, 6, 20), then it would be a lot easier to just do:

```
foreach(range(1,$role_level-1) as $level):
    echo "<option value='$level'>Level $level</option>";
endforeach;
```

And, yes, your idea will be effective enough to do a basic permissions system.

Answer (score 1):

If the roles are as static as you say (1,2,3,4), then I would recommend skipping an additional database hit and just use a quick `for` loop!

```
<select>
<?php
for( $iRole = $role_level - 1; $iRole > 0; --$iRole )
    echo '<option value='.$iRole.'>'.$iRole.'</option>';
?>
</select>
```

Otherwise, you seem to be on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

ok you can have a table that contains the permissions.and if the number of levels are not so much you can also create different db accounts.with different accesses to different parts.

and be careful that you should check the person and the thing he/she wants to do.I mean just showing a option is not enough and you should check the permissions in the server-side.

and you can create actions and users(roles) just as @STT LCU said.

but this is not enough because you need a code or a class like permission checker.which with it you can check the permission like the.

```
if($perm->IsHaveAccess('editing_post')){
//the logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one really good solution to your problem. It's ACL(Access Control List).

There are roles and resources and you gives access to it :)

There is example from Zend Site.

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
    ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('member'))
    ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

$parents = array('guest', 'member', 'admin');
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('someUser'), $parents);

$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('someResource'));

$acl->deny('guest', 'someResource');
$acl->allow('member', 'someResource');

echo $acl->isAllowed('someUser', 'someResource') ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

More on http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html

I am taught that if there is something written and it's good and works, there is no sense in wasting time to write something new.

These roles, recources and relations between them you can keep in database and just load it when you need it.

This is very basic example, Zend_Acl gives you a very powerful tool it's up to u how you use it. If you don't want to use Zend Class you can look at it and design your class in similar way.